# How do you get SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins to use a web proxy?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Before you leap to answer: This is about the plug-in in the Jenkins Web UI. I have the proxy working for sonar-scanner in my pipelines. I need a fix for the plug-in in the web UI.

I'm getting blank pages in the Jenkins web UI on projects and builds using SonarQube. I get this in https://jenkins.example.com/log/all (not actually example.com:

```
Error fetching project information
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
...
Caused: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request https://sonarqube.verafin.com/api/server/version
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:212)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:154)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:143)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.HttpClient.getHttp(HttpClient.java:37)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.WsClient.getServerVersion(WsClient.java:82)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.SQProjectResolver.resolve(SQProjectResolver.java:60)
...
```

I have a web proxy between Jenkins and SonarQube.

I've confirmed access to my SonarQube over HTTPS from my Jenkins server and my Jenkins agents using curl through the web proxy (confirmed with curl -v that the web proxy is definitely used). Jenkins can download and install plug-ins successfully.

How do you get SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins to use a web proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. I have created a ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJNKNS-302

Comment: Thank you, Julien. I will follow this in your JIRA.